# in Dart, how do you use `class` when stored in a variable?

Tags: class, dart, instantiation

in `Dart`, you can assign a `class` to a variable, eg,

```
var klass = String;
```

but once assigned, how do you used it?

```
var str = new klass(); ===> ERROR: malformed type used
```

once one has a `class` in a variable, how does one use it to `instantiate` a new `object` of that `class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [dart:mirrors](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_mirrors.html).

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class A {
  A();
  A.named(String value);
}

main() {
  final t = A;

  // same as 'new A()'
  final a1 = reflectClass(t).newInstance(const Symbol(''), []).reflectee;

  // same as 'new A.named('test')'
  final a2 = reflectClass(t).newInstance(#named, ['test']).reflectee;
}
```